# zu infinitiv when 2 verbs go together?

Tags: verb, compound

For example: gehen essen are 2 verbs go together (z.B. Ich gehe essen jetzt). However, with zu + infinitiv what is the correct way to put zu?

- Es ist schon spät, mit dir **zu** essen gehen
- Es ist schon spät, mit dir essen **zu** gehen

Comment: 1) is incorrect, 2) is correct

Comment: 2) may be syntactically correct, but does not make sense.

Comment: @RHa any suggestion for that?

Comment: Nitpick: *Ich gehe essen jetzt* sounds odd to me, perhaps *Ich gehe jetzt essen*?

Comment: @RHa, it makes perfect sense: "It is too late to go to eat with you".

Comment: @vonbrand That would make sense, but it's not what it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think with a *zu* clause, the *zu* + verb comes after any objects of the the verb. So it's *Es ist leicht, dich zu sehen* rather than *Es ist leicht, zu dich sehen.* In this case the object is the infinitive verb *essen*, and while infinites are normally pushed to the end of the sentence, it doesn't get pushed past the *zu* in a *zu* clause. In the comments RHa objected to your example (though I don't see the problem myself), so I'll try a different one: *Ich denke daran, angeln zu gehen.*